# list classes by folder/directory using doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I would like to display all the classes within a given directory (and its subdirectories)
from the doxygen generated documentation.

I could use doxygen /addtogroup and other group commands, but I would like to
do this without having to add group tags for each classes within a given directory.

the SHOW_DIRECTORIES options does generate a "Directory" tab/panel but it displays all the files for a given directory and not the classes.

How can I do that ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nicolas I'm after then same thing. It is not still possible.

Looking at the todo list (does not exists anymore, see issue tracker) it doesn't seem to be one of the top features to implement:

> `[priority: 6 (out of 10)]` Option to automatically create group things based on the directory structure of a project.

Comment: This item is not on the todo list anymore. Has it been implemented?